# Spring to load the CSV file as List of Object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, csv

In My Spring MVC application
I want to load CSV, like I can load properties file.

```
@Resource(name = "myProperties")
private Map<String, String> myProperties;
@Bean(name="myProperties")
    public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("user-form-validation-configuration.properties"));
        return bean;
    }
```

Currently I am using `org.apache.commons.csv`

Please let me know, if spring provide any util for csv file.

Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 0):

CSV file is not a Properties file. So you cannot convert it to a `Map<String, String>`

You should inject the class in `org.apache.commons.csv` package as a Spring bean and then use it to read in your application. Or you can also try `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader` from Spring Batch

Comment: Thanks Dhanush for the response.Yes I want to inject the csv file.Currently I am using Class Loader.Please let me How to inject the csv file  ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());